# Is there a way for me to show a customized message on the lock screen?

Tags: android

I'm using DevicePolicyManager to make an app that can lock devices and was wondering if there was a way to show a custom message on the lock screen if I lock the device with DevicePolicyManager.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There should be a way to show some kind of Activity above the Log-Screen (like the Winamp-App does it).

I found the [`FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED`-flag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED) which seams to do just that.

Also, I found [this recourse](http://code.google.com/p/mylockforandroid/wiki/LockActivity) which illustrates how this works.