# how android calendar shows the event notification in locked screen mode?

Tags: android, calendar, notifications

I am working on an app which shows notification for the upcoming meetings. Android calendar is able to show the notification while the phone is in locked mode but my application can't do it. Please help me achieving the same for my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A while ago i already answered a similar question, it might help you, too: [Is there a way for me to show a customized message on the lock screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920613/is-there-a-way-for-me-to-show-a-customized-message-on-the-lock-screen/6920663#6920663)