# How to ignore button click of "Recent Activity Button" in android 3.0

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, statusbar

My question is self explanatory.
I have searched a lot but could not found the way to handle Recent activity button click.
I want to ignore the hardware button clicks of Recent Activity button from the status bar from android 3.0 tablet.

Currently what I have tried so far is:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

       if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) 
       { 
              return true;
       }
       // in the same way I have written it for KEYCODE_HOME
}
```

can you tell me what should I write to handle recent activity button?

Thanking you in advance. :)

**EDIT:** This is what I have tried now. The KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH is not working.

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        Log.e("INSIDE", "LOCKDEMO");
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            Log.e("KEY EVENT", "BACK");
            return true;
        }
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) {
            Log.e("KEY EVENT", "HOME");
            return true;
        }
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.FLAG_FROM_SYSTEM) {
            Log.e("KEY EVENT", "SYSTEM");
            return true;
        }
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.FLAG_KEEP_TOUCH_MODE) {
            Log.e("KEY EVENT", "TOUCH MODE");
            return true;
        }
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.FLAG_SOFT_KEYBOARD) {
            Log.e("KEY EVENT", "SoFT KEYBOARD");
            return true;
        }
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.FLAG_VIRTUAL_HARD_KEY) {
            Log.e("KEY EVENT", "HARDWARE KEY");
            return true;
        }
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH) {
            Log.e("KEY EVENT", "APP SWITCH");
            return true;
        }

        Log.e("KEY EVENT", "NOT HANDLED");
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

When I press on RecentAppBtn, it does not even print the last Log statement i.e. Event not handled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From peeking into the docs, I think that [`KeyEvent.KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH) is what you're searching for.

You could however also use the [`KeyEvent.getKeyCode()`-method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#getKeyCode%28%29) (on the `event`-parameter) to see which key-code is triggered (and if there is any key triggered), when you press the application switcher.

---

I played around with this for a while and I have come to the conclusion, that it's not possible.

The `KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH`-event is not delivered to either [`onKeyDown()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onKeyDown%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29) nor [`dispatchKeyEvent()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#dispatchKeyEvent%28android.view.KeyEvent%29). Ergo, It can not be handled.

Also, you'll run into problems on Android 4 devices, because the [`KEYCODE_HOME`-event](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_HOME) is also no longer dispatched to any of the above methods. See the docs:

> Key code constant: Home key. This key is **handled by the framework
>   and is never delivered to applications**.

---

It also seems that there is no real easy approach to creating a real lock-screen yourself. See this discussion: [Developing a custom lock screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529608/android-how-to-develop-custom-lock-screen)

It is well possible to show some custom information on the default lock-screen: [Is there a way for me to show a customized message on the lock screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920613/is-there-a-way-for-me-to-show-a-customized-message-on-the-lock-screen/6920663#6920663)

---

For the sake of completeness: In Android L, you'll be able to "lock users in your app", so you don't need to manually override the Hardware keys. Here's the [relevant information](http://developer.android.com/preview/api-overview.html#TaskLocking):

> The L Developer Preview **introduces a new task locking API that lets
>   you temporarily restrict users from leaving your app** or being
>   interrupted by notifications. This could be used, for example, if you
>   are developing an education app to support high stakes assessment
>   requirements on Android. **Once your app activates this mode, users will
>   not be able to see notifications, access other apps, or return to the
>   Home screen, until your app exits the mode.**

Comment: Basically, I have implemented (custom)lock screen facility in my app where UI will be visible to user but he cannot click on any view from the UI, so for that I have disabled home and back key as well but if user presses the recent activity button, the app can get minimized which I don't want to happen. KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH is also not working. So can you tell me is it possible to ignore this event?

Comment: @Shrikant have you checked if there is a KeyEvent being generated when you tap that button? Like I explained above.

Comment: Hi Lukas! I am still stuck with this problem. And yes I checked what you have asked. I have updated my question. Can you please help me on this?

Comment: @Shrikant I did some further research and updated my answer. Have a look.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run your app rooted in Kiosk-mode, then it might be possible to disable **com.android.systemui** and replace buttons by soft buttons (for instance the Button Saviour app, though be careful not to brick your device!). It seems a lot of cosmetic stuff disappears and I don't know if it affects system stability in some unknown way, but I have made it work so far.

If anyone knows more about **com.android.systemui**, what it really does and if it is safe to disable it, please comment!

Also see my post:
[Safe to disable com.android.systemui?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29229474/is-it-safe-to-disable-com-android-systemui)

where I hope to get some answers...

Comment: On a rooted device I suggest you use Xposed instead. It's better.