# Is it safe to disable com.android.systemui?

Tags: android, user-interface, root, android-recents

I have found that Android recent app dialog can be disabled by disabling
package **com.android.systemui**. I want to run my (rooted) device in kiosk mode so it is essential that the recent apps dialog not be shown on long press.

Now, exactly what does **com.android.systemui** do? I don't need notifications and power indicators and stuff so it is OK if that kind of cosmetic stuff disappears. It is also OK if soft input home buttons disappear because I have replaced them with a software app (Button saviour).

Is it safe to disable **com.android.systemui**, or do I risk subtle system hangs in certain unclear situations? To put it shortly -is it just another app, or is it absolutely essential to the Android operating system? (I haven't experienced any problems this far!)

Is **com.android.systemui** available in all Android versions?

Answer (score 5):

If you completely remove SystemUI.apk from the system, your device will hang on start-up and never fully boot again. Tried it before. ;) Framework-res and the system have some dependencies on SystemUI.

The correct, *non-invasive* way to get rid of SystemUI is to have an application that force-closes it upon `BOOT_COMPLETED` via `am force-stop com.example.systemui` or `kill <PID>`. Depending on device SystemUI restarts itself (not always), if it does you'll have to set a `Timer` that repeats the kill process. There's an [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.infolife.taskmanager) on Play store that does this, but I can't say for the reliability.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks for your input. Though I never removed it completely I just disabled it and had no problem this far. Either you can go into Settings/Apps/All/[app name for com.android.systemui] and press inactivate. Alternatively you can use adb with packetmanager:
**adb shell pm disable com.android.systemui**
I believe they are equivalent. This way your dependendcies are (probably) still met (always?). Though, I wonder if this will work always in all situations....

Comment: I mean you kill systemUI but do you know for sure if it will always work in all situations if you do that?

Comment: SystemUI is somewhat device dependant as well. I didn't question my own generalization when I bricked a phone once by doing it. I suppose you can take my answer as a warning.

Comment: JohnyTex it will never hard-brick a device. If your manufacturer made custom themes or other dependencies that rely on SystemUI the worst that can happen is your system freezing up until rebooted.

Comment: Did you soft-brick a device by **pm disable com.android.systemui**?

Comment: I did by renaming it from .apk to .bak. I think you may have a point there.

Comment: Tried to install a systemui mod from XDA and in the process replaced my systemui with the one they provided. After a reboot I had no lock screen, no status bar, the stock notification panel gone (thanks to material notification shade I'm having a second option) and am now typing this comment from the very same phone (on which I did the aforementioned thing 10 mins back) with every app in full immersive mode.  Impressive that my phone's stil running. If u want I can send screenshots.

Comment: Can anyone explain this. I'm completely periplexed

Answer (score 2):

I have it disabled on my phone succesfully via removal; gone is the ugly top bar with the notifications and clock.

Drawbacks are that native screenshots won't work nor does the recent apps switcher, but both issues can be fixed via replacements.

Battery life increases slightly due to lower CPU usage.

(I9500 cyanogenmod 11)

Comment: Did a different thing but got the same result.